# Calling an OSGi service from the command line

Tags: java, cmd, osgi, apache-felix

I have an OSGi project running on the Felix framework with several services.  I need to access one of those services from the command line (not from the OSGi shell).  Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java program that runs from the command line? You can't access the service registry without using Java (or another JVM language).

Alternatively you could of course expose an API as a RESTful web service for example, and access your services over that API from outside the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi services are only available inside the local OSGi framework. So you would need to use some remoting to reach them from another process. [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/remote.html) which builds upon felix supports a command client which uses ssh to access the running server. So this way you could execute commands of the OSGi shell from the OS command line. That might help in your case.